# Ignore previous asynchronous call and execute the latest

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous, async-await, concurrency

I'm using React,

I have a button that calls an asynchronous function on every onClick event:

```
<MyButton onClick={handleClick}>
  Next
</MyButton>
```

Then a function that takes time to load data:

```
const isExecuting = useRef(false);

const handleClick = async () => {
  if (!isExecuting.current) {
    isExecuting.current = true;
    try {
      resetViews();
      await chargeViews(patientId);
    } finally {
      isExecuting.current = false;
    }
  }
};
```

So for example when I click 5 times, it will receive 5 calls and all of them will be executed in order, I need a way to just execute the latest call and ignore the previous 4 calls, so it won't take time to execute all of them.

PS: I thought of disabling the button until the function finishes executing, but as I'm using the button to load the next `patient`, this won't be convinient because we'd be obliged to wait for 4 patients to be loaded to load the 5th patient.

Comment: The term to google is "Debounce", for example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24004791/can-someone-explain-the-debounce-function-in-javascript

Comment: https://github.com/domenic/last will help you. Source: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23277694/can-i-ignore-a-promise-in-javascript

Answer (score 1):

`Debounce` is one option and the option is to pass ref and get it cancelToken when you are trying to hit again the same API it will cancel the previous call If exist and call the new API request the below example is the general solution or you can send cancelToken from component and call it before the new API call

```
// dummy Api
const chargeViews = async (sourceRef,patientId) => {
  console.log({patientId})
  try {
    let token = undefined;
    if (sourceRef) {
      const CancelToken = axios.CancelToken;
      const source = CancelToken.source();
      token = { cancelToken: source.token };
      sourceRef.current = source;
    }
    const response = await Axios.get(`endpointURL`, token)
    return response.data;
    // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-explicit-any
  } catch (err: any) {
    throw new Error(err);
  }
};
```

component

```
const sourceRef = React.useRef(null);

const handleClick = async () => {
    try {
      if (sourceRef.current) sourceRef.current.cancel();
      await chargeViews(sourceRef, patientId);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error)
    }
};

<MyButton onClick={handleClick}>
  Next
</MyButton>
```

Comment: I see that you used axios, I'm not loading data from a server, but from an image, does the solution still convinient for my situation?

Comment: what do you mean by that ?

Comment: I'm using a library, so in chargeViews I'm not using axios, I'm using a function from that library that take an URL of an image in the server and return a promise containing image data.

Comment: oh! so see the documentation of that library on how to cancel requests that a common behavior to cancel request.